# SingleSChildScrollView moves up in IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, mobile-development

I'm having a little issues with SingleChildScrollView in iOS.

the app works well on android but moves up in iphoneXr.
picture below.

[image]

Code follows.

```
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(3, 9, 23, 13),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(

              child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                top: -50,
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  height: 1000,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/component.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: new BackdropFilter(
                    filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 12.0, sigmaY: 12.0),
                    child: new Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `SafeArea` to contain your SingleChildScrollView, like this:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
       child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(),
        ),
    ),
);
```